# how to access a specific bit in an int variable in x86 assembly to check if it is 0 or 1?

Tags: x86

how to access a specific bit in an int variable in x86 assembly to check if it is 0 or 1?

I thought this would work, but it doesn't

```
int main()
{
  int num = 3; //stored as a 32 bit binary I assumed something like ...011

  //now I need to test the 2nd bit of num
  __asm  
  {  
    test num, 1 // By the way, how would I check the ZF flag?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `aex` you mean `eax`.

If you just want to test bit 0 of `eax` you can do:

```
test eax, 1
; ZF will be set based on eax AND 1. eax remains unchanged
jnz bit0_is_set
; The jump wasn't taken, so bit 0 was clear
...
jmp done
bit0_is_set:
; The jump was taken, so bit 0 was set
...
done:
```

To test other bits, use increasing powers of two: 2 for bit 1, 4 for bit 2, 8 for bit 3, etc.

---

If you really want to copy bit 0 of `eax` to `ebx` you can do:

```
mov ebx, eax
and ebx, 1
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get, and for which line of code? I see no reason for `test` to cause an error. I've used it myself in VC++ inline assembly code.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the changes I made and focused the question title more on what problem I am trying to solve

Comment: Question, to test the rightmost bit I would want to say "test eax, 1". Is it because 2 to the zero is 1? Why not "test eax, 0"? Otherwise, very, very helpful answer.

Comment: Right. What `test` does is perform a bitwise `AND` between the two operands, updates the flags based on that, and throws away the result.